# GORM events not firing in integration tests

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Trying to integration test Grails GORM delete on an object with beforeDelete event.  Problem is that the beforeDelete event is not being fired in Integration Tests:

```
class ChallengeMembershipTests extends GroovyTestCase {
     void testQuitChallenge() {
      VUser user = VUser.build()
      assertNotNull("user should be saved", user.id)
      UserChallenge challenge = UserChallenge.build(owner: user)
      assertNotNull("challenge should be saved", challenge.id)

      ChallengeMember member = ChallengeMember.build(challenge: challenge)
      println "MEMBER: ${member}"
      assertNotNull("member should be saved", member.id)
      member.delete(flush:true)        

  }
}
```

Relevant part of ChallengeMember:

```
  def beforeDelete = {
      log.info "begin deleting challenge member ${this}"
      user.removeFromChallenge_memberships(this)
      challenge?.removeFromParticipants(this)
      team?.removeFromMembers(this)
      log.info "deleting challenge member ${this}"
  }
```

Grails 1.3.5

Any suggestions?

Why do I care?

My tests are failing due to:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.v.ChallengeMember#1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.v.ChallengeMember#1]

But, delete works fine from a browser, because beforeDelete is being fired.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I wrap in in a withNewSession it fires-

```
ChallengeMember.withNewSession {
   membership.delete(flush:true)
}
```